# A function that tries a range of values of different variables to produce maximum sum

Tags: python

I have this equation LR = 500/(30x + 40y + 10z) and I want to find the combination of x,y and z that give the maximum denominator with the condition that x,y,z are between 0.8 and 1.2 and the denominator cannot be greater than 500. (**Note**: the numbers are random and may not have a solution, I just need the code). Here is what I have so far.

```
def LR(p, incd):
    p = 10*x + 20*y + 30*z
    p < 500
    incd = 3
    x = range(0.8, 1.2)
    y = range(0.8, 1.2)
    z = range(0.8, 1.2)
    LR = incd/p   
    return x,y,z
```

Comment: Have you considered using sympi?

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense for plain Python – for example, ``p = 10*x + 20*y + 30*z`` and ``p < 500`` isn't sensible at all to do what you want with just builtins. Are you using some library?

Comment: The general problem you are trying to solve is called "optimization" and there are many, many available approaches to the problem.  [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) implements many such algorithms, including support in many cases for bounds constraints.